# Is it possible to save the filelist of the Swift compiler?

Tags: swift

Please check the following (partial) Swift compiler call:

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift -frontend -c -filelist /var/folders/fg/ssznc5j55yq1f9yngt82gyr40000gn/T/sources-7a8f3f`

My question is about the "-filelist" option. The Swift compiler sometimes (it is unknown in what circumstances) generates some temporary file list that is used as input for the compiler call. After the call the file list is gone. Is there any way to make this file list persistent, i.e. is it possible to save it somewhere for later use?

I am asking this question because I would like to apply the compiler call myself after this, but since the file list is gone after compilation, this doesn't work.

Comment: Where that file list is being stored ?

Comment: Shouldn't the filelist file end with `.LinkFileList` extension? You've cut that out? It's created at [these lines](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/35fbdcb8acc22364f3984a51c1fe5055d03b86c6/lib/Driver/DarwinToolChains.cpp#L227-L232) But I couldn't find where that file is filled though.

Comment: The `.LinkFileList` is a different type of "filelist". The one the author asks about doesn't have any file extension, and contains a newline-separated list of filenames of swift files (perhaps all the swift files in the module?). I believe the purpose of the filelist is to shorten the `swift` compiler invocation when compiling each swift file. Not sure if a filelist is always used, or only under certain conditions (eg if more than N number of swift files in a module).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `'OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS=-save-temps'` in your `xcodebuild` invocation.

Source: This [blog post](https://danielbeard.io/2016/08/17/swift-file-compile-times.html) mentions the `-save-temps` flag.